# How to implement push notification like done in facebook iPhone app

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to know how implement push notification like facebook iPhone app.
Means push notification will come on a image top place  which is present  in the my app.
How to do that? push notification on  the app icon has been done..
Give me your ideas..